# PrimeNG Button not Stylizing

Tags: angular, button, styles, stylesheet, primeng

So I'm trying to stylize my PrimeNG button to have an orange background like this:

```
<button pButton class="orange-button" label="Click Me".....>
```

and then in my style sheet doing

```
.ui-button.orange-button {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

However the button remains the same color as the omega theme being used. How can I override this? I'm using angular 2 and using Angular CLI so I have it linked to a style sheet in the .ts file.

Comment: How did you do it? None of the answers work.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

use `important` to override the styles.

```
.ui-button.orange-button {
    background-color: orange !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two topics to remember for styling PrimeNg.

**Component DOM**

The PrimeNG component often contains HTML tags inside it.

You might be styling the PrimeNG component and not the HTML it contains. For example, the `p-button` component wraps a `button` so to make a button 100% width requires styling the `p-button` and the `button` (or button class) to 100%.

Using the `pButton` directive, like you do in your example, rather than the `p-button` component helps simplify the style needed to change the component.

**CSS Specificity**

PrimeNG is fairly specific so custom CSS needs to be more specific.

W3Schools describes specifity at https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp.

Basically styling `button` isn't specific enough. You may need to style `some-component button` instead to be more specific.

With SCSS that might look like:

```
my-component {
     .ui-button {
         .orange-button {
             background-color: orange;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the ::ng-deep pesudo class selector on the primeng element:
if you using LESS or sass style:

```
::ng-deep pButton 
{
  .ui-button.orange-button
  {
    background-color: orange
  }
}
```